# lapply error message when creating a sequence

Tags: r, list, lapply

I was wondering why the lapply function gives an error back when using this term:

```
>lapply(x=3:9, seq)
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

but does work perfectly, when running it like this:

```
>lapply(X=3:9, seq)

[[1]]    
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]    
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[3]]    
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[4]]    
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[5]]   
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[6]]    
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[7]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Both objects (**x** and **X**) are not available.

Is there some kind of internal functions at work here?

Assa

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `lapply` is

```
function (X, FUN, ...)
```

so it has two named parameters: `X` and `FUN`. When you use `X=3:9`, it's setting the first parameter to `3:9`. When you run `x=3:9`, then this parameter is being passed in the `...` part (since R is case sensitive) and then `seq` is now the first parameter. It is customary not to use the name for the first parameter when calling `lapply`. just use

```
lapply(3:9, seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lapply` function requires 2 arguments `X` and `FUN`. Since R is case sensitive, it will not work with `x` instead of `X`. The error message is about `FUN` but the real problem is your `x`.

I recommend to look at the help page when you use a new function by running `?lapply`.